# Pegar evento que aconteceu na página

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Existe alguma maneira de ficar monitorando os eventos que estão acontecendo na página?

Alguma função que deixe registrando no `console.log` por exemplo, não sei, é só um exemplo..

Existe uma maneira de pegar isso?

Por exemplo, se eu clicar na página eu sei que é um evento de click, mas existem outros eventos personalizados que acontecem em determinados momentos que eu não conseguiria saber por si só, por isso minha dúvida.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode iterar nas propriedades do objeto `document` e criar um *event listener* apenas nas propriedades que começam com "on", como **on**click, **on**blur, **on**mouseover etc. que são as propriedades dos eventos.

No `addEventListener` você coloca o evento sem o "on", por isso o uso do método `substr()`, por exemplo, no evento `onclick`:

```
on    -> prop.substr(0,2)
click -> prop.substr(2)
```

O `e.type` imprime o nome do evento disparado.

```js
for(let prop in document){
   if(prop.substr(0,2) == "on"){
      document.addEventListener(prop.substr(2), function(e){
         console.log(e.type);
      });
   }
}
```

> Agora, como são mais de 80 eventos, recomendo você listar apenas os
>   eventos desejados ou os mais comuns. Imagino que você não queira
>   escutar absolutamente todos os eventos possíveis. Neste caso você pode
>   criar um array apenas com os eventos que desejar escutar, por exemplo:

```js
var eventos = ['click', 'blur', 'mouseover', 'mouseup', 'mousedown'];
for(let evt of eventos){
   document.addEventListener(evt, function(e){
      console.log(e.type);
   });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Não é recomendado você escutar todos os eventos por conta da performance, porém, para casos de teste você pode adicionar vários event listeners da seguinte forma:

```
Object.keys(window).forEach(key => {
    if (/^on/.test(key)) {
        window.addEventListener(key.slice(2), event => {
            console.log(event);
        });
    }
});
```

O objeto **window** pode ser substituído pelo elemento que você deseja testar, por exemplo:

```
Object.keys($('.teste')).forEach(key => {
    if (/^on/.test(key)) {
        $('.teste').addEventListener(key.slice(2), event => {
            console.log(event);
        });
    }
});
```

E depois, caso queira filtrar por key e mouse apenas, pode realizar da seguinte forma:

```
Object.keys(window).forEach(key => {
    if (/^on(key|mouse)/.test(key)) {
        window.addEventListener(key.slice(2), event => {
            console.log(event);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  alert ("Hello World!");
}
```

ai onde ta 'click' vc pode colocar no nome do evento que vc quer escutar tipo 'load', 'keypress' e outros

Comment: Sim, obrigado. Mas, se eu não souber o nome do evento? Por isso a pergunta, monitorar todos os eventos da página pra poder identificá-los

Comment: se isso for possível vai deixar seu site muito mau otimizado pois so de vc movimentar o seu mouse do inicio ao fim da tela vc executa dezenas de eventos imagina vc tendo que colocar o javascript pra ler isso tudo. eu recomendo fazer um array dos mais utilizados

Answer (score 0):

Para monitorar os eventos que estão acontecendo na página, deves primeiro buscar os eventos disponíveis na página e ouvir cada evento individualmente.

Exemplo:

```
  window.onload = () => {
  var ev = '';
  var allEvents = [];

  // Busca todos os eventos disponiveis no navegador
  for (ev in window) {
    if (/^on/.test(ev)) {
      // Adiciona cada evento disponivel
      document.addEventListener('' + ev.replace('on', ''), function(event) {
        console.log('Event: ', event.type);
      }, false);
    }
  }
}
```

**Note que você não usa o prefixo "on" para o evento; use "click" em vez de "onclick".**